# sequences-show that $\inf\{x_{n}: n\in \mathbf{ N}\}>0$

Tags: analysis

Knowing that $x_{n}>0$ for each $n \in\mathbf{N}$ and $x_{n}\rightarrow x>0$. Let $B$={$x_{n}:n \in\mathbf{N}$}. How could I show that $\inf B>0$??

Comment: Hint: Show that there exist $n$ such that for all $m>n$, $x_m>x/2$.

Comment: Ok!!! thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the definition of limit and fix $\varepsilon = x/4$. Then there is $n$ such that for all $m \geq n$ $|x_{m}-x|\leq x/4$. For $m\geq n$ $x_{m} \geq 3/4x$. So the inf restricted to $m \geq n$ is at least $3/4x$. Now look at $m<n$. Since it is a finite set of real numbers, it has a minimum $y$, which is >0 by your assumptions. So the global inf is $\geq \mathrm{min}\left( 3/4x,y\right)>0$.

Comment: Nice!!Thanks!!!